# How to cast a generic type to a non-generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that looks like this (assume that I have the necessary method GetMySerializedDataArry() and my serializer JsonSerializer):

```
    public static List<T> GetMyListOfData<T>()
    {
        var msgList = new List<T>();

        foreach (string s in GetMySerializedDataArray())
        {
            msgList.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(s));
        }

        return msgList;
    }
```

This works fine and as expected.

However, I want to use the same method to optionally, if and only if the generic type is specified as string, return the data unserialized like this (which does not compile and has syntax problems):

```
    public static List<T> GetMyListOfData<T>(bool leaveSerialized)
    {
        if (typeof (T) != typeof(string) && leaveSerialized)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter must be false when generic type is not List<string>", "leaveSerialized");
        }

        var msgList = new List<T>();

        foreach (string s in GetMySerializedDataArray())
        {
            if (leaveSerialized)
            {
                // Casting does not work:  "Cannot cast expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' to type 'List<string>'"
                // I've tried various permutations of "is" and "as"... but they don't work with generic types
                // But I know in this case that I DO have a list of strings..... just the compiler doesn't.
                // How do I assure the compiler?

                ((List<string>)msgList).Add(s);
            }
            else
            {
                msgList.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(s));
            }
        }

        return msgList;
    }
```

My questions are in the inline comment.... basically though the compiler clearly doesn't like the cast of generic to non-generic, it won't let me use permutations of "is" and "are" operators either, I know I actually have the correct string in this case.... how to assure the compiler it is OK?

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:  SOLUTION**

Thanks to Lee and Lorentz, both.  I will be creating two public methods, but implementing the code in a private method with the admittedly icky decision tree about whether to leave serialization.  My reason is that my real-world method is far more complex than what I posed here to SO, and I don't want to duplicate those business rules.

**FINAL EDIT:  CHANGED SOLUTION**

Although both answers were very helpful, I have now been able to detangle business rules, and as a result the "correct" answer for me is now the first -- two different methods.  Thanks again to all.

Comment: Why not simply two methods? One generic and one non-generic?

Comment: Although I agree with @Lorentz, another option would be to cast `msgList` to an `IList` rather than `IList<String>` and simply call Add(Object item) which is equivalent the solution suggested by @Lee

Comment: Thanks all -- Of course I provided a much more simple version of my method, which has a lot of business logic in it before we get to the msg add.  I also think I agree with Lorentz in general.... but in particular the duplication of code for the business logic would be a problem.  I think I will implement public wrappers of two different methods that then both call the same private method which will use Lee's proposed solution.  My thanks to all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not return a list of strings as a list of T. I would suggest that you use two separate methods and skip the parameter:

```
public static List<T> GetMyListOfData<T>()

public static List<string> GetSerializedMyListOfData()
```

The advantages of this approach is

1. It's more readable (imo) `GetSerializedMyListOfData()` vs `GetMyListOfData<string>(true)`
2. You also know the intent of the caller at compile time and don't have to throw an exception when the type argument don't match the intent to leave the data serialized

Comment: I think Lorentz is correct, you should use two methods to do this. It doesn't seem to make sense to use a generic method to do this.  The only other thing I thought of would be to use an ArrayList (which can take any object), but I think that might get more complicated down the line unless you're just trying to dump to a feed or something ambiguous.

Comment: I had been coming to this conclusion.  The only problem is that my actual method is far more complex in its business rules, so I am hesitant to want to duplicate that code.  May be the lesser of two evils though.

Comment: I'm going to split the difference here.  Two public methods as @Lorentz suggests, but both calling the same private method under the hood and using Lee's approach...

Comment: @StephanGolux updated my answer with another approach that will work. However, I still recommend the first approach if you can somehow extract the business logic. If you leave the business logic in the string only method, you only need json deserialize the results of the string method in the generic method.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it.  Removing business logic will not be trivial.... appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can cast to `object` first:

```
((List<string>)(object)msgList).Add(s);
```

however a cleaner solution could be to create another method for dealing with strings, this would also allow you to remove the `leaveSerialized` parameter.

Comment: I'm going to split the difference here. Two public methods as Lorentz suggests, but both calling the same private method under the hood and using @Lee's approach...